# Why can't I use 'sudo su' within a shell script? How to make a shell script run with sudo automatically

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, heredoc, su

I cannot figure out what's wrong with my bash script. When I run it in terminal, command by command run every command separately in terminal, it works.

```
#!/bin/bash    
sudo su <<EOF
mkdir /home/ubuntu/backup/
cp "$(ls -t /usr/lib/unifi/data/backup/autobackup | head -1)" /home/ubuntu/backup/
curl --insecure --user root:password -T "$(ls -t /home/ubuntu/backup/ | head -1)" sftp://vps2.duckdns.org:/root/backup.unf
EOF
```

However, when I run the above bash script, give me plenty of erros

```
bash -v test.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo su <<EOF
mkdir /home/ubuntu/backup/
cp "$(ls -t /usr/lib/unifi/data/backup/autobackup | head -1)" /home/ubuntu/backup/
curl --insecure --user root:password -T "$(ls -t /home/ubuntu/backup/ | head -1)" sftp://vps2.duckdns.org:/root/backup.unf
EOF
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/unifi/data/backup/autobackup': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/backup/': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
curl: (78) Could not open remote file for reading: SFTP server: No such file
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trying to execute the command substitutions in the original shell, which runs with the regular user's permissions. They need to be executed by `su`. Quote the `EOF` token to prevent expansions in the here-document.

```
sudo su <<'EOF'
```

Comment: Many thanks @Barmar you save my day ;) Just one more thing, how can I automate with date stamp the file that I upload trough sftp `sftp://vps2.duckdns.org:/root/backup_datestamp.unf`

Comment: Use `$(date +'format_string')` to put the date in the filename.